# Is it OK to inject a specialization into the std namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization

In this [article on defining your own extensions to `::std::error_code`](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-4.html) the author recommends this code:

```
namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct is_error_code_enum<http_error>
    : public true_type {};
}
```

in order to enable conversions from your own error constants to the system error type.

Is this reasonable? It always makes me nervous to put things into the `std` namespace. Is there a better way of accomplishing the goal? Failing all that, is there a part of the standard that says this is always OK to do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yep, specializations (for user-defined types) of existing std types are the *only* thing you're allowed to put in the `std` namespace, as long as the specialization meets the requirements for the original template.

See 17.6.4.2.1 in the C++0x draft.

New types, function overloads and anything else, of course, is forbidden. But specializations of existing templates is allowed.

Comment: You have the better answer, but @Steve314 includes the important detail that in some cases you absolutely have to do this. I will likely wait a few hours (just on general principles) and then probably accept this one.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't just OK - it's essential in some cases. What you shouldn't do is to define entirely new functions/classes/templates within std.

`std::swap` in particular is a common and simple thing to specialise. Some classes need to do this to allow efficient swaps, basically swapping private references to exchange internals rather than using the default temporary-and-assignments implementation.

**EDIT**

The comment by ildjarn mentions ADL - [Argument Dependent name Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). The Wikipedia page specifically mentions `std::swap` in the "Interfaces" and "Criticism" section.

Section 13.5.2 of Stroustrup (Special Edition) includes an example of specialization of `std::swap`. Quoting from that...

> These specializations of `less()` and `swap()` are used in the standard library (16.3.9, 20.3.16). In addition, they are examples of widely applicable techniques.

I've always read that as indicating that specialization of `std::swap` was the right thing to do, and I've never worried enough about ADL to question that, but it's possible there's a gap between "used in the standard library" and "widely applicable techniques" - that this technique *shouldn't* be used to specialise `std::swap` to handle types that aren't in `std`.

It's also possible that there is a style issue that hadn't been decided back when the special edition was first published. AFAIK, Stroustrup has added some extra appendices and applied some errata, but otherwise not substantially revised the content.

Based on the Wikipedia page, there *is* a potential problem with mixing the addition of specialisations and ADL - sometimes you can get ambiguity preventing any lookup. This *only* happens if you mix the two techniques, and ADL is know for leading to semantic issues anyway. But that argument only leads to "don't use ADL at all", but ADL does exist for a reason.

Well, yes, ADL exists for a reason - so that non-member functions and operators that work with a time are visible along with the type. But `std::swap` isn't associated with one particular type - it's generic, with only particular specializations being associated with particular types. If you want `std::swap` to be visible, you want the `std` namespace. ADL isn't necessary to make that work and, as the Wikipedia page points out, there are criticisms of ADL.

What this means is, basically, that I don't know. I have my rationalisations. They don't necessarily agree with more widespread style rules. Certainly this comment proves that it's not *essential* to specialise `std::swap` - you can supply your own separate `swap` and rely on ADL instead. Maybe that's preferred.

I'll probably come back and edit again after I've checked.

Comment: `std::swap` should **not** be specialized or overloaded -- instead, one should put a `swap` free function in the same namespace as the type being swapped, and let ADL do the rest.

Comment: @ildjarn - thanks - I'm not sure you're right yet, but see the edit.

Comment: ADL was widely broken in major compilers for quite some time, so specializing `std::swap` became standard practice. However, with modern, more standard-conformant compilers, that workaround is no longer necessary.

Comment: The problem with relying on ADL is that a lot of code explicitly calls `std::swap`, rather than `swap`. I don't really see the argument in favor of relying on ADL for `swap`. I ca nsee it working most of the time, but I don't see why it'd be a *superior* option

Comment: @jalf - I think my problem is that I see overloading not as selecting from many different functions, but as compile-time dispatch - selecting from multiple implementations of one function. And I think of the namespace as part of the name of the function. From that point of view, relying on ADL in this case is horrible - `whatever::swap` and `std::swap` are conceptually two unrelated functions, not just different implementations. The trouble with that is it may just mean I have the wrong mental model.

Comment: @jalf - Your comment is interesting, as it shows a roughly opposite problem to the one in the Wikipedia page - whether ADT seems superior or specialisation within `std` seems superior may depend primarily on whether people tend to use `using namespace std;`. If you use `using`, you may get the ambiguity issue (an `std::swap` and an `other::swap` both equally valid). If you don't, you may get the nothing-found issue (`other::swap` not found because you explicitly called `std::swap` rather than just `swap`). Using ADT seems to force the use of `using namespace`.

Comment: @Steve: I agree with you on ADL, and I don't think it's "the wrong mental model" per se.

Comment: @Steve314 : There cannot be any ambiguity in that scenario, because overload resolution always prefers non-templates over templates. And the proper thing to do for `swap` in particular is a using declaration rather than a using directive.